# typescript in jupyter notebook

Tags: typescript, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run typescript on jupyter notebook.

I tried using `npm install -g itypescript` but I get just javascript kernel.

I am using anaconda and I have already installed nodeJS.

Comment: Could you send error message?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak there is no real error, it just not recognizes the types syntax.
the name of the kernel is "javascript (node.js)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to installing the TypeScript npm package:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

You also need to install the kernel. The following installs it globally:

```
its --install=global
```

In both cases you may need to use sudo.

Answer (score 10):

You can check if the kernel is registered to Jupyter by `jupyter kernel spec` command.

```sh
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3       /home/yunabe/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  typescript    /home/yunabe/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/typescript
```

If `typescript` is not listed here, you failed to register the kernel when you installed it for some reason.

### Another typescript kernel

Even if you could install `itypescript` kernel correctly, you may find the kernel is not very useful in your use case because it does not allow you to redefine a variable with the same name by design. If you execute `function f() {}`, you just get an error message like `TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.`.

If you think `itypescript` does not fit to your use case, please try it out a new kernel I recently implemented too:

[yunabe/tslab - JavaScript and TypeScript Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/yunabe/tslab)

It was designed and implemented differently from `itypescript` and it may fit well in your use case.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was really going nuts thinking I was doing something wrong just because I wanted to change the value of a const!